# How to decode a laravel session json?

Tags: php, laravel

```
a:4:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"PQ0eKCZm6fpBGy1UaalRVLLbSIc5OqqRptbfhOZy";s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}s:4:"test";s:3:"123";s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1395620563;s:1:"c";i:1395619755;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}}
```

I'am reading this string from the laravel session file handler, how can I decode an array for example?

`json_decode` doesn't helped

Comment: Try [`unserialize`](http://ca1.php.net/unserialize).

Answer (score 4):

This is `serialize`d data. Use [`unserialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Demo:

```
php> unserialize('a:4:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"PQ0eKCZm6fpBGy1UaalRVLLbSIc5OqqRptbfhOZy";s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}s:4:"test";s:3:"123";s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1395620563;s:1:"c";i:1395619755;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}}');
array (
  '_token' => 'PQ0eKCZm6fpBGy1UaalRVLLbSIc5OqqRptbfhOZy',
  'flash' => 
  array (
    'old' => 
    array (
    ),
    'new' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
  'test' => '123',
  '_sf2_meta' => 
  array (
    'u' => 1395620563,
    'c' => 1395619755,
    'l' => '0',
  ),
)
```